# How to migrate/clone full linux vps?

Tags: ubuntu, vps

What's the best way to full migrate (data, configuration files etc) a VPS ?

In particular I've a VPS hosted from an hoster to another.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run your organization's backup restore procedure, targeting new instances on a different hosting provider.

Do some testing like you would for a new operating system version. There may be differences in implementation details, how auth or networking works, specific software package versions, that kind of thing.